# How to Transform single thread into a Multithread python script?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to put my single thread script into a Multi-thread script for increase performance by parallels tasks.
The botleneck is the latency for request the registrar, i want to launch more than 1 request for increase the performance.

```
find_document = collection.find({"dns": "ERROR"}, {'domain': 1, '_id': 0})

for d in find_document:
    try:
        domaine = d['domain']
        print(domaine)
        w = whois.whois(domaine)
        date = w.expiration_date
        print date
        collection.update({"domain": domaine}, {"$set": {"expire": date}})
    except whois.parser.PywhoisError, err:
        print "AVAILABLE"
        collection.update({"domain": domaine}, {"$set": {"expire": "AVAILABLE"}})
```

What is the best way? Using Pool with map? Another way?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: first you have to determine what you want multi-threading / multi-processing to do for you.. do you want to take advantage of downtime while waiting on file writes? do you want to maintain interactivity for a user while this computes in the background? are you looking for performance gains by using more cores?

Comment: I'm looking for increase performance by using more cores.

Comment: do you know if you're limited by compute speed, file writes, or network speed? (if you're dealing with the internet probably socket waiting..)(you should update your problem to reflect this or someone may flag as too broad)

Comment: I'm limited by latency of the request from registrar, i want to start x parallels requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with the internet you can see real performance gains from threads without going to the trouble of multiprocessing because of the ability to wait on multiple requests at once. any time you're doing parallel execution however you're going to have potential issues with printing to stdout or file writing.. This can be easily fixed with a thread lock.

in your case I would simply create a single thread for each of `d in find_document`

each thread takes several args including:

- target=foo # a function that the thread will call when it is started
- args=() # args foo will be called with
- kwargs={} # you get the picture

I also re-ordered your `try-except` to limit the number of lines in the try block (good practice). to do this I added an `else` block, which is a very good thing to know is possible (also with for and while loops). This also allowed me to group your print statements together so they could be locked off to prevent separate threads from printing things at the same time and getting out of order output. Lastly, I didn't know what your collection object was and if it's update method was thread safe, so I wrapped that in a lock as well.

```
import threading

find_document = collection.find({"dns": "ERROR"}, {'domain': 1, '_id': 0})

def foo(d, printlock, updatelock):

    domaine = d['domain']
    try:
        w = whois.whois(domaine) #try to keep only what's necessary in try/except block
    except whois.parser.PywhoisError, err:
        with printlock:
            print(domaine)
            print("AVAILABLE")
        with updatelock
            collection.update({"domain": domaine}, {"$set": {"expire": "AVAILABLE"}})
    else:
        date = w.expiration_date
        with printlock:
            print(domaine) #move print statements together so lock doesn't block for long
            print(date)
        with updatelock
            collection.update({"domain": domaine}, {"$set": {"expire": date}})

updatelock = threading.Lock() #I'm not sure this function is thread safe, so we'll take the safe way out and lock it off
printlock = threading.Lock() #make sure only one thread prints at a time

threads = []
for d in find_document: #Create a list of threads and start them all
    t = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(d,printlock,updatelock,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start() #start each thread as we create it

for t in threads: #wait for all threads to complete
    t.join()
```

As per your comments, you have too many jobs to try to run them all concurrently, so we'll need something more like the multiprocessing pool than my earlier example. The way to do this is to set up a given number of threads that loop over the given function consuming new arguments until there are no more arguments to consume. For the sake of leaving the code I already wrote, I'll just add this as a new function that also calls `foo`, but you could write it all into a single function.

```
import threading

find_document = collection.find({"dns": "ERROR"}, {'domain': 1, '_id': 0})

def foo(d, printlock, updatelock):

    domaine = d['domain']
    try:
        w = whois.whois(domaine) #try to keep only what's necessary in try/except block
    except whois.parser.PywhoisError, err:
        with printlock:
            print(domaine)
            print("AVAILABLE")
        with updatelock:
            collection.update({"domain": domaine}, {"$set": {"expire": "AVAILABLE"}})
    else:
        date = w.expiration_date
        with printlock:
            print(domaine) #move print statements together so lock doesn't block for long
            print(date)
        with updatelock:
            collection.update({"domain": domaine}, {"$set": {"expire": date}})

def consumer(producer):
    while True: 
        try:
            with iterlock: #no idea if find_document.iter is thread safe... assume not
                d = producer.next() #unrolling a for loop into a while loop
        except StopIteration:
            return #we're done
        else:
            foo(d, printlock, updatelock) #call our function from before

iterlock = threading.Lock() #lock to get next element from iterator
updatelock = threading.Lock() #I'm not sure this function is thread safe, so we'll take the safe way out and lock it off
printlock = threading.Lock() #make sure only one thread prints at a time

producer = iter(find_document) #create an iterator from find_document (expanded syntax of for _ in _ with function calls)

threads = []
for _ in range(16): #Create a list of 16 threads and start them all
    t = threading.Thread(target=consumer, args=(producer,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start() #start each thread as we create it

for t in threads: #wait for all threads to complete
    t.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this !

Comment: It seems to work fine but the fact that I have millions of domains in my list, the launch of all threads simultaneously exploded mongodb. I would have to be able to limit the number of threads. How can I do ?

Comment: I didn't know what sort of scale this project was.. for something like that you'll want to produce a sort of producer - consumer schema.. I'll write up a short example for that too..

Comment: Thank you in advance Aaron for your answer.